# Design IC backup with supercapacitor

Tags: switching-regulator, supercapacitor

I trying to design RF IoT device. In case of power failure, the device must send power-off notification before shutdown. So the MCU and RF transceiver must to stay powered at least 1 minute.

In schematic below are two VDD. First is for powering all components(display, etc.) and second (VDD_BACKUP) is only for MCU and RF transceiver.
MCU and RF transceiver current together will be ~60mA during transmitt.

In case of short period 12V outage, occurs switch to VDD_BACKUP and after 12V ON again, occurs switch back to VDD. 
But thanks to softstart, occurs a unwanted MCU restart.

It is there a better solution?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question again.

Comment: Why does it take a minute to send the off-notification?

Comment: Is your MCU + transceiver current 60mA average, or 60mA peak? What is your transmit power (dBm)?

Comment: Related/alternative solution: see e.g. MQTT https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270863/mqtt-what-is-the-purpose-or-usage-of-last-will-testament

Answer (score 1):

Linear Technologies offers the LTC4041, which seems to provide exactly what you're looking for, automatic switching between a main power and a backup power source. It looks like it supports both Li-ion and supercaps.

http://www.analog.com/en/products/LTC4041.html#product-overview

The LTC4041 is a complete supercapacitor backup system for 2.9V to 5.5V supply rails. It contains a high current step-down DC/DC converter to charge a single supercapacitor or two supercapacitors in series. When input power is unavailable, the step-down regulator operates in reverse as a step-up regulator to backup the system output from the supercapacitor(s).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to add some RC filtering on the automatic switching circuit so as to not switch back to the main power source until a certain time after it is restored, and after the soft start time.  E.g. a cap across R106 might do it.

Another option might be to remove the automatic switching and just use two diodes, one from Vdd and another from 3V3_STEPUP.  If the step-up voltage is set just below the Vdd level, the main circuit would not draw from the supercap until the main source is lost.  As soon as it's restored that Vdd voltage will eventually come back up again and resume supplying power to the load.

You would lose some voltage in the diodes (Vf), so you might need to adjust your feedback resistors for U102 to increase the Vdd voltage.   You might also need to change U103 if your circuit can't run off 3.3V-Vf when in backup mode.  Use Shottky diodes to minimize voltage drop.

If your load draws a moderate amount of power, the diodes will cause power loss, and in that case your original circuit would be preferred from an efficiency standpoint.  But this circuit also benefits from simplicity, reliability, and lower cost.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBXyyI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>